# Why null/undefined checks does not work in Classes with extendable props interface in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package.json, tslint, tsconfig

Null/undefined checks do not work in classes that accepts generic props.

```
interface IFooProps {  
    minDate?: Date;
}
```

1 - this gives "undefined is not assignable to type "Date"" error in updateDate function when calling createNewDateWithMonth5 function

```
class Foo<P extends IFooProps> extends React.Component<P> {  

    updateDate() {  
        if (this.props.minDate) {  
            this.createNewDateWithMonth5(this.props.minDate)
        }
    }

    createNewDateWithMonth5(date: Date): Date {  
        const newDate = new Date(date);
        newDate.setMonth(5);
        return newDate;
    }
}
```

2 - this gives no error and works as expected.

```
class Foo extends React.Component<IFooProps> {  

    updateDate() {  
        if (this.props.minDate) {  
            this.createNewDateWithMonth5(this.props.minDate)
        }
    }

    createNewDateWithMonth5(date: Date): Date {  
        const newDate = new Date(date);
        newDate.setMonth(5);
        return newDate;
    }
}
```

I was expecting 1 to work like 2 without any error.
Why null/undefined checks do not work in extendable classes with extendable props.

Here is the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-platform-9v260) to reproduce the error.

Comment: I have no idea why TypeScript can't narrow down the type, but if you do this `if (this.props.minDate instanceof Date)` it works. Strange...

Comment: Indeed, it works. But I still wonder why null check does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an online IDE where the problem can be reproduced (stackblitz, codesandbox, codepen, repl.it, etc)?  I haven't seen the error in my environment and without a reproduction it's hard to say what's happening.  Please see the guidelines about what constitutes a [mcve] and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure, does seem a bit strange, but on the other hand I'm not surprised - never know what's happening in the super-class.

I would cache the prop, and then do the same thing with the cached value. This should be fool-proof.

```
updateDate() {
    const { minDate } = this.props
    if (minDate ) {  
        this.createNewDateWithMonth5(minDate)
    }
}
```

This "destructuring" syntax is also extremely popular with react, as it shortens the code a lot as there is no need to write "props" or "state" for each reference.

Comment: This still doesn't work. `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'.`

Comment: Now that's even more weird. Try checking explicitly if (minDate !== undefined).
If that doesn't work then there's something wrong with your environment.

For reference, here's a online template where your exact code is compiling without problems: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-sunset-oonjo?fontsize=14

Comment: I'm not OP, but I tried with `minDate !== undefined` and even with a custom type guard `function isUndefined(val): val is undefined {
  return val === undefined;
}`, none of which worked. Only `instanceof` guard worked.

Comment: Maybe this is happening because the props are never assigned. You could try if adding the constructor with props parameter passed to super-class helps.

I can't reproduce :/

Comment: I know I can use destructuring assignment and all sorts of crazy type checks for every possible falsy value(in this case just null and undefined.) but simply I don't want to. And curios of why even this ever happens.

Comment: Adding constructor to class changed nothing, Besides, as far as I know, react already puts one default constructor for you if you don't supply one..

Comment: Try comparing your package.json / tsconfig.json with the ones in codesandbox.io/s/billowing-sunset-oonjo?fontsize=14

At this point it would have to be either a TS configuration or IDE issue.

Comment: You have react 16.8.4, I have 16.8.6. I removed everything from my tsconfig(since yours is nearly empty) nothing changed and kept giving the same error.

Comment: Removing "strictNullChecks": true from the tsConfig removed the error. But, I don't think they are related because after "strictNullChecks" property, it accepts everything, even without null check as the name suggests :)

Comment: I agree. Removing "strictNullChecks" is not a real fix. Still clueless what's happening.